# Converting IP addresses from char * to uin32_t

Tags: c

I was inspired by [Conversion of IP address to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283703/conversion-of-ip-address-to-integer)

My code looks like this:

```
    uint32_r parseIPV4string(char * ipAddress){
    char ipbytes[4];
    sscanf(ipAddress, "%uhh.%uhh.%uhh.%uhh", &ipbytes[3], &ipbytes[2], &ipbytes[1], &ipbytes[0]);
    return ipbytes[0] | ipbytes[1] << 8 | ipbytes[2] << 16 | ipbytes[3] << 24;
}
```

Virtually an exact copy, my problem is however, that my ip addresses aren't coming out properly. I am watching in shock and awe as "129.173.118.0" and "129.173.31.187" both return 2164260864

Can someone explain what is going on?

Perhaps I am using the parser incorrectly, I am unsure exactly how it works, namely the "%uhh." are new to me and I have no idea as to whatever is going on in that return statement.

Comment: This is why you check the return value of `scanf` and friends

Comment: `"%hhu"` the modifier should come first And it should be `unsigned char ipbytes[4];`

Comment: Note that these are signed chars, and they get sign-extended to ints.

Comment: why reimplement inet_pton() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `sscanf` is failing. When this happens, it leaves the arguments in an indeterminate state.  So your `return` statement returns garbage.

`%uhh` means to read into an `unsigned int` , and then match the letter `'h'` twice.  If your input string did not actually contain `h` after the first number, then matching fails and `sscanf` will return `1`  (or `0` if there wasn't even a first number).

You probably meant `%hhu`, to read an integer and store in an `unsigned char`, however you also need to make `ipbytes` be `unsigned char` to match the format specifier.  The specifier for plain or signed char is `%hhd`.

This array should be unsigned anyway, otherwise your `|` later on is going to mess up (remember that negative numbers have a lot of `1` bits set, in 2's complement).

A further problem is that if your system has 32-bit int, then even when using `unsigned char`, the expression `ipbytes[3] << 24` causes undefined behaviour if the high bit of `ipbytes[3]` is set, due to signed integer overflow: the *integer promotions*  unfortunately promote `unsigned char` to a signed `int`.

Finally, if the system has 16-bit int then the `<< 16` and `<< 24` fail entirely.

A robust way to write the function would be to avoid any undesirable promotions:

```
uint32_t parseIPV4string(char const * ipAddress)
{
    unsigned int ip[4];

    if ( 4 != sscanf(ipAddress, "%u.%u.%u.%u", &ip[0], &ip[1], &ip[2], &ip[3]) )
         return 0;   // or some other indicator or error

    return ipbytes[3] + ipbytes[2] * 0x100 + ipbytes[1] * 0x10000ul + ipbytes[0] * 0x1000000ul;
}
```

If you really want to use `|` and `<<` then you either have to use some ugly casts;  or change `ip` to have the type `uint32_t` in which case `"%u"` must be replaced by `"%" SCNu32`.

Comment: My solution does not detect the case where the input has numbers larger than `255` (it will return junk in that situation) - although your original code didn't handle that well either.  To detect this case you could add an extra line , e.g. `if ( (ip[0] | ip[1] | ip[2] | ip[3]) >= 0x100 ) return 0;`