# Unix - how to get IP address of domain name?

Tags: c, unix, localhost, hosts-file

In a C program in UNIX, gethostbyname() can be used to obtain the address of domain like "localhost". How does one convert the result from gethostbyname() to dotted decimal notation.

```
struct hostent* pHostInfo;
long nHostAddress;

/* get IP address from name */
pHostInfo=gethostbyname("localhost");

if(!pHostInfo){
    printf("Could not resolve host name\n");
    return 0;
}

/* copy address into long */
memset(&nHostAddress, 0, sizeof(nHostAddress));
memcpy(&nHostAddress,pHostInfo->h_addr,pHostInfo->h_length);
```

nHostAddress contains the following:

```
16777243
```

How do I convert the result so that I can get the output as :

```
127.0.0.1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680365/integer-to-ip-address-c

Comment: You just have to format it properly; each byte corresponds to one IP field (e.g. first byte is `127`, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert from a `struct in_addr` directly to a string using `inet_ntoa()`:

```
char *address = inet_ntoa(pHostInfo->h_addr);
```

The value you've got (16777243) looks wrong, though -- that comes out to 1.0.0.27!

Comment: Probably to do with the endianness of his computer or something.

Comment: I could understand 1.0.0.127, but the 27 is inexplicable.

Comment: It actually comes to be 1.0.0.127, @duskwuff please check it again.

Comment: Odd... I'm using `socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack(">L", 16777243))` in a Python shell and getting `'1.0.0.27'` out.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy Just Compile This Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
int main()
{
    struct hostent *ghbn=gethostbyname("www.kamonesium.in");//change the domain name
    if (ghbn) {
        printf("Host Name->%s\n", ghbn->h_name);
        printf("IP ADDRESS->%s\n",inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)ghbn->h_name) );
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK `gethostbyname` is now obsolete. One should use `getaddrinfo`.

Comment: This returns a garbage IP. "localhost" resolves to `108.111.99.97`, which isn't even my real IP...

Answer (score 1):

The `inet_ntoa()` API does what you're looking for, but is apparently deprecated:

https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/inet_ntoaman.html

If you want something more future-proof-IPV6ish, there's `inet_ntop()`:

https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/inet_ntopman.html

Comment: Both of those links no longer exist

Comment: @MichaelDodd Updated.  But, generally speaking, you can perform such updates yourself with a "suggested edit".  Fixing broken links is the kind of thing that is usually approved.

Comment: I'm aware, I have enough rep to edit questions and answers directly. However, C isn't my strongest area so I didn't want to update your answer with something that could potentially be wrong or misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The variable "**h_name**" in the last statement needs to change as "**h_addr**" shown in follows:

printf("IP ADDRESS->%s\n",inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)ghbn->h_addr) );

Comment: Was this meant to be a comment on one of the other answers?