# Improving MySQL Performance on a Run-Once Query with a Large Dataset

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb

I previously asked a question on how to analyse large datasets ([how can I analyse 13GB of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449965/how-can-i-analyse-13gb-of-data)). One promising response was to add the data into a MySQL database using natural keys and thereby make use of INNODB's clustered indexing.

I've added the data to the database with a schema that looks like this:

```
TorrentsPerPeer
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ip       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| infohash | varchar(40)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The two fields together form the primary key.

This table represents known instances of peers downloading torrents. I'd like to be able to provide information on how many torrents can be found at peers. I'm going to draw a histogram of the frequencies of which I see numbers of torrents (e.g. 20 peers have 2 torrents, 40 peers have 3, ...).

I've written the following query:

```
SELECT `count`, COUNT(`ip`) 
    FROM (SELECT `ip`, COUNT(`infohash`) AS `count`
              FROM TorrentsPerPeer
              GROUP BY `ip`) AS `counts`
    GROUP BY `count`;
```

Here's the `EXPLAIN` for the sub-select:

```
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------+------------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table          | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_length | ref    | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------+------------+--------+----------+-------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | TorrentPerPeer | index | [Null]        | PRIMARY | 126        | [Null] | 79262772 | Using index |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------+------------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

I can't seem to do an `EXPLAIN` for the full query because it takes way too long. This [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44802) suggests it's because it's running the sub query first.

This query is currently running (and has been for an hour). `top` is reporting that `mysqld` is only using ~5% of the available CPU whilst its `RSIZE` is steadily increasing. My assumption here is that the server is building temporary tables in RAM that it's using to complete the query.

My question is then; how can I improve the performance of this query? Should I change the query somehow? I've been altering the server settings in the `my.cnf` file to increase the INNODB buffer pool size, should I change any other values?

If it matters the table is 79'262'772 rows deep and takes up ~8GB of disk space. I'm not expecting this to be an easy query, maybe 'patience' is the only reasonable answer.

**EDIT** Just to add that the query has finished and it took 105mins. That's not unbearable, I'm just hoping for some improvements.

Comment: can you show the table structure? can you use an `explain` command?

Comment: what is the maximum peer amount per ip?

Comment: @jcho360 The table structure is in the question, I don't have any other tables. I'll run `EXPLAIN` now and update the question when it finishes.

Comment: I mean can you make a `desc tablename` to se yours PK, FK, UNIQUES, INDEX

Comment: @Sebas That's a tricky question, currently I'm considering that each unique ip is a unique peer. I know that this is a poor assumption but I'm hoping to be able to remove outliers later in the analysis.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant: max infohash amount per peer_id

Comment: @jcho360 Done, there's not a lot to it

Comment: @Sebas There's no hard limit, previous analysis seemed to suggest that it tops out at ~500 torrents for a single ip. I'm not very confident in that being correct though.

Comment: now make a `explain SELECT `count`, COUNT(`ip`) 
    FROM (SELECT `ip`, COUNT(`infohash`) AS `count`
              FROM TorrentsPerPeer
              GROUP BY `ip`) AS `counts`
    GROUP BY `count`;`

Comment: @jcho360 I've added the `EXPLAIN` for the sub-select but running ti for the full query looked like it was going to take a very long time.

Comment: @Sebas The completed query tells me that there is one ip linked to 1042463 torrents (a slight outlier). :)

Comment: that doesn't make sense, did you make `explain` of all the query??? or just the internal select?

Comment: do you have COMMON PK??create INDEX to `ip` and another INDEX to info

Comment: @jcho360 Which bit doesn't make sense? I ran `EXPLAIN` for the whole query and it didn't finish. I Googled why this might be the case and found the MySQL bug that says that the sub-query is run before the `EXPLAIN` happens. This was obviously going to take a long time so I stopped it and ran the `EXPLAIN` on the sub-select only.

Comment: @jcho360 COMMON PK as in both fields together form the PK? Yes. You are saying that separate indexes will speed up the query?

Comment: ohh I see, create the index on each columns and let me know how it goes

Comment: This specific query looks like a good candidate for Map Reduce. If SQL is not a requirement it might be worth trying something like MongoDB Map Reduce and comparing it's performance to your SQL databse. If you think the data set could grow to order of hundreds of GBs, then you start getting into the realms where hadoop Map Reduce jobs across a few machines come into their own for this sort of task.

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that with an unsigned int and a varchar 40 (especially the varchar!) you have now a HUGE primary key and it is making your index file too big to fit in whatever RAM you have for Innodb_buffer_pool. This would make InnoDB have to rely on disk to swap index pages as it searches and that is a LOT of disk seeks and not a lot of CPU work.

One thing I did for a similar issue is use something in between a truly natural key and a surrogate key. We would take the 2 fields that are actually unique (one of which was also a varchar) and in the application layer would make a fixed width MD5 hash and use THAT as the key. Yes, it means more work for the app but it makes for a much smaller index file since you are no longer using an arbitrary length field.

OR, you could just use a server with tons of RAM and see if that makes the index fit in memory but I always like to make 'throw hardware at it' a last resort :)