# How do I print IP addresses with bpf_trace_printk()?

Tags: c, printing, ip, trace, bpf

I want to print IP addresses of packets parsed by an XDP program I am testing with. I using `bpf_trace_printk()` to print details about packets parsed by my program.
How can I print IP addresses with `bpf_trace_print()`?

I tried using [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680365/integer-to-ip-address-c/1680421#1680421) to print the IP, but I get this error when trying to use `bpf_trace_printk()`

```
/virtual/main.c:99:52: warning: cannot use more than 3 conversion specifiers
            bpf_trace_printk("\n- src_ip: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", src_ipaddr[3],src_ipaddr[2],src_ipaddr[1],src_ipaddr[0]);
                                                   ^
6 warnings generated.
error: /virtual/main.c:111:59: in function filter i32 (%struct.xdp_md*): too many args to 0x5b6de28: i64 = Constant<6>
```

Its not clear to my why I am getting this error.

Comment: Just a guess: `bpf_trace_printk` is _not_ as general as `printk` or `printf`. Based on the diagnostic, its limit for format specifiers is 3, so you can only have (e.g.) `%d.%d.%d`. I'm not too familar with BPF, but you could [probably] loop to get what you want: `bpf_trace_printk("\n- src_ip:"); for (int idx = 3;  idx >= 0;  --idx) bpf_trace_printk("%c%d",(idx == 0) ? ' ' : '.',src_ipaddr[idx]); bpf_trace_printk("\n");`

Comment: Is `src_ipaddr` an IPv6 or an IPv4 address?

Comment: src_ipaddr is neither, its an unsigned character pointer array.

Answer (score 1):

There are `printk` [format specifiers](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.20/core-api/printk-formats.html) for IP addr structs. You can just do this:

```
bpf_printk("%pI6", &ip6hdr->saddr);
```

And the result:

```
12:46 $ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe
            ping-648648  [001] d.s11 191981.300511: bpf_trace_printk: 2001:0569:7c1b:8500:2587:6500:1975:5649
            ping-648648  [001] d.s11 191982.318736: bpf_trace_printk: 2001:0569:7c1b:8500:2587:6500:1975:5649
            ping-648684  [000] d.s11 191983.422204: bpf_trace_printk: 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
            ping-648684  [002] d.s11 191984.430712: bpf_trace_printk: 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
```

Answer (score 0):

**`bpf_trace_printk` is meant for debugging only.** It will print a large warning in your system logs when you use it. If you're at the stage where you want to pretty-print IP addresses, then you're probably not debugging anymore.

**The proper alternative is to use the `bpf_perf_event_output` BPF helper.** See https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/docs/tutorial_bcc_python_developer.md#lesson-7-hello_perf_outputpy for an example with bcc. That will allow you to send arbitrary data to userspace, where you can pretty-print the IP addresses with Python.

Comment: If you're not using bcc but something else, I'm happy to share another example.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this (ipv4 only and C23):

```
static char* be32_to_ipv4(__be32 ip_value, char *ip_buffer) {
    __u64 ip_data[4];

    ip_data[3] = ((__u64) (ip_value >> 24) & 0xFF);
    ip_data[2] = ((__u64) (ip_value >> 16) & 0xFF);
    ip_data[1] = ((__u64) (ip_value >> 8) & 0xFF);
    ip_data[0] = ((__u64) ip_value & 0xFF);

    bpf_snprintf(ip_buffer, 16, "%d.%d.%d.%d", ip_data, 4 * sizeof(__u64));
    return ip_buffer;
}


#define BE32_TO_IPV4(ip_value) ({ \
    be32_to_ipv4((ip_value), (char [32]){}); \
})
```

Then you can do e.g. (some of my code):

```
 bpf_printk("bpf_sock:original_tuple: saddr:sport=%s:%d, daddr:dport=%s:%d",
                       BE32_TO_IPV4(original_tuple.ipv4.saddr), bpf_ntohs(original_tuple.ipv4.sport),
                       BE32_TO_IPV4(original_tuple.ipv4.daddr), bpf_ntohs(original_tuple.ipv4.dport));
```

Answer (score -1):

Linux kernel provides BPF helper, `bpf_trace_printk()`, with the following definition:

> long bpf_trace_printk(const char *fmt, __u32 fmt_size, ...);

So you need to define size of format string before your arguments.

A hard limitation is that `bpf_trace_printk()` can accept only up to 5 input arguments in total. You must define `fmt` and `fmt_size`, which means you limit to use just 3 other arguments. So 4 specifiers is not allowed in format string. This is quite often pretty limiting and you might need to use multiple `bpf_trace_printk()` invocations to log all the data.

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
   bpf_trace_printk("IP section %d [%d]", strlen("IP section %d [%d]"),i,src_ipaddr[i]);
```

or use @craig-estey method

```
bpf_trace_printk("\n- src_ip:"); 
for (int idx = 3;  idx >= 0;  --idx) 
    bpf_trace_printk("%c%d",(idx == 0) ? ' ' : '.',src_ipaddr[idx]); 

bpf_trace_printk("\n");
```

I'm not sure but you may use sprintf

```
char part1Ip[32] = {0};
char part2Ip[32] = {0};
char wholeIp[32] = {0};
sprintf(part1Ip, "%d.%d", src_ipaddr[3],src_ipaddr[2]);
sprintf(part2Ip, "%d.%d", src_ipaddr[1],src_ipaddr[0]);
sprintf(wholeIp, "%s.%s", part1Ip,part2Ip);

bpf_trace_printk("\n- src_ip: %s\n", wholeIp);
```

For more information see [BPF tips & tricks](https://nakryiko.com/posts/bpf-tips-printk/).